# bar progress in tkinter with thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

hello people I have a problem, with a progress bar in tkinter, you will see:

I execute a method and I want that while this action is being performed, a progress bar appears, the problem is that the bar does not stop when the method ends, I don't know how to do that ... some help please

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Progressbar example")
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_action)
        self.button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def start_action(self):
        self.button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.contar)
        windows_bar = WinProgressBar(self)
        self.after(t.start())

    def contar(self):
        for i in range(1000000):
            print("está contando", i)
        return True


class WinProgressBar(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.title("Barr progress")
        self.geometry("300x200")
        self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, mode="indeterminate")
        self.progressbar.place(x=30, y=60, width=200)
        self.progressbar.start(20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `after()` needs function's name without `()` - `self.after(t.start)` - but all this line seems useless.

Comment: `thread` at start could set `finished = False` and at the end set `finished = True` . And main code should use `self.after()` to run code which will check if `finished == True` and stop prorgessbar. But safer can be use `query` instead of variable `finished`. `thread` should put information in queue and main code should use `after()` to check if there is information in queue and stop progressbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to stop it in threat

```
def contar(self):
    for i in range(500):
        print("está contando", i)
    
    self.windows_bar.progressbar.stop()
    self.windows_bar.destroy()
    self.button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
```

---

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Progressbar example")
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_action)
        self.button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def start_action(self):
        self.button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.contar)
        t.start()

        self.windows_bar = WinProgressBar(self)
        
    def contar(self):
        for i in range(500):
            print("está contando", i)

        print('stop')            
        self.windows_bar.progressbar.stop()
        self.windows_bar.destroy()
        self.button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        
        
class WinProgressBar(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.title("Barr progress")
        self.geometry("300x200")
        self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, mode="indeterminate")
        self.progressbar.place(x=30, y=60, width=200)
        self.progressbar.start(20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

---

Many GUI frameworks don't like to change widgets in thread and then you can use variable `self.running` (which will be shared between both threads) to inform program if thread is running.

```
def contar(self):
    self.running = True

    for i in range(500):
        print("está contando", i)

    self.running = False
```

and in main thread you can use `after()` to periodically check this variable to stop progressbar and/or close window - and this time main thread is changing widgets.

```
def check_thread(self):
    if self.running:
        self.after(1000, self.check_thread) # run again after 1s (1000ms)
    else:
        print('stop')
        self.windows_bar.progressbar.stop()
        self.windows_bar.destroy()
        self.button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
```

---

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Progressbar example")
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_action)
        self.button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def start_action(self):
        self.button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.contar)
        t.start()

        self.windows_bar = WinProgressBar(self)

        self.check_thread() # run first time
        
    def contar(self):
        self.running = True
        for i in range(500):
            print("está contando", i)
        self.running = False

    def check_thread(self):
        if self.running:
            self.after(1000, self.check_thread) # run again after 1s (1000ms)
        else:
            print('stop')
            self.windows_bar.progressbar.stop()
            self.windows_bar.destroy()
            self.button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        
        
class WinProgressBar(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.title("Barr progress")
        self.geometry("300x200")
        self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, mode="indeterminate")
        self.progressbar.place(x=30, y=60, width=200)
        self.progressbar.start(20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

---

If threads can't share variables then you can use `queue` to send information from thread to main thread.

```
import threading
import queue
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Progressbar example")
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_action)
        self.button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def start_action(self):
        self.button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        
        self.q = queue.Queue()
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.contar, args=(self.q,))
        t.start()

        self.windows_bar = WinProgressBar(self)
        
        self.check_queue()
        
    def contar(self, q):
        for i in range(200):
            print("está contando", i)
        
        q.put('finished')
        
    def check_queue(self):
        if self.q.empty() or self.q.get() != 'finished':
            self.after(1000, self.check_queue)
        else:
            print('stop')
            self.windows_bar.progressbar.stop()
            self.windows_bar.destroy()
            self.button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        
        
class WinProgressBar(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.title("Barr progress")
        self.geometry("300x200")
        self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, mode="indeterminate")
        self.progressbar.place(x=30, y=60, width=200)
        self.progressbar.start(20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```