# Python - Progress Bar in Tkinter crashing

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, progress-bar

I am trying to show a progress bar on a for loop, the for loop works but the process bar doesn't advance, only the window shows up but it freezes. The process ends regularly and the window is still.

Here is what I've got so far, I tried using a tkinter class but it did the same thing. It works when I start the process with a function inside the button, but that won't work with the whole process I am trying to do.

This is what happens:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAtoN.png) The frozen progress bar.

This is the code where I am testing the progress bar:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import time


# Waiting screen, start button
root = Tk()
var = IntVar()
button = Button(root, text="Start", command=lambda: var.set(1))
button.pack()
print("waiting...")
button.wait_variable(var)
print("done waiting.")

# Creation of progress bar
total = 100
root = Tk()
progress = Progressbar(root, length=400, mode='determinate')
label = Label(root, text=f'Processing {total} files').pack()
progress.pack()
c = 0
for i in range(total):
    time.sleep(.1)
    print(i) # Several functions nested in loop
    c += 1
    progress['value'] = c
    root.update_idletasks()

    if c == total:
        root.destroy()

progress.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `root.update_idletasks()` to `root.update()`.  It is not recommended to create more than one instance of `Tk()` and I wonder why the for loop is not inside a function called by the button command.  Also it is better to run time-consuming task in a thread.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Apparently, that is working. And I definitely need to look into threading.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two roots, we used toplevel. And I took out the progress call part as a function so that it can be called again. Also changed time.sleep(0.1) to top.after(100). And I changed the import part a bit.

so, code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar

def progress_start():
    var.set(1)
    total = 100
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    progress = Progressbar(top, length=400, mode='determinate')
    label = tk.Label(top, text=f'Processing {total} files').pack()
    progress.pack()
    c = 0
    for i in range(total):
        top.after(100) #100ms
        print(i) # Several functions nested in loop
        c += 1
        progress['value'] = c
        progress.update()

        if c == total:
            top.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=progress_start)
button.pack()
print("waiting...")
button.wait_variable(var)
print("done waiting.")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I am not doing everything inside a function because I need to return from the "several functions nested" in the loop. And I am unsure how I could do that if the only call to the function is inside a button.

Comment: Consider using the threading module. In this case, this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63836979/bar-progress-in-tkinter-with-thread) seems to be helpful.